# How to update Shared Prefrences data when user updates the app?

Tags: android, version-control, sharedpreferences

I was just wondering that as suppose I am storing something in android app e.g - in Shared Preferences and suppose current version of app is `n` and in the updated version `(n + 1)`, I changed the data type of my shared preference object from `List<String>` to `List<Object>`, and in the next updated version which is `(n+2)` I have updated the data type of object to `List<Double>` now when user will go to play store update his/her app, then the previous data will be there so I would have to write some code by myself that if previous version is `n` and current version is e.g - `(n+2)` now I will change the value in the Shared Prefrence in the code accordingly by writing the `if-else` to check what is the older version.

Is above the approach you developers use when you update any android app on the playstore?

Also Is there any possiblity like for example user has `(n+2)` version of my app currently installed and now user wish to download any older version of my app e.g version `n`, now Is there any possibility that user will be able to install this version `n` app while also having data restored for version `(n+2)`, because if that will happen then as in my version `n` code, there will be no `if-else` to change data type of object from `List<double>` to `List<String>` ?

I am a newbie, have never put any app on playstore but going to, that's why asking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I'm completely changing the type of Object that belongs to a certain preference key, and I'm going to publish that to production, I'm going to just change the key I use to avoid the hassle of updating it conditionally. This really isn't something that should happen at all though. If you're changing things that drastically, users aren't going to be happy any way you handle it.

To answer your second question, you can't downgrade Android apps, ie go from versionCode 3 to versionCode 2, directly. The only way to do this is to first uninstall the current version, thus clearing any SharedPreferences anyway, and install the older version. If you're using the backup feature Google gives you, the preferences might be restored, which brings me back to my first point: if you're going to change it that much, just change the key you're using.

(Google Play doesn't let users downgrade for the reason I described. It will serve users the latest version that is compatible with their device.)

Comment: If you are going to change the key only then also you would have to write the logic to insert previous key values to the new key, and for that you would have to write `if-else`?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur if you're completely changing the object type that's in that key, you shouldn't be keeping the value anyway.

Comment: Sorry but by completely I mean I can convert old values to new values, for e.g I was storing amount as `string` in the first place but now I am storing amount as `double`?

Comment: Why would you do that? String can already encapsulate a double value, and even if it's not the most efficient way, it's not limiting you. Changing it to use Double after the app is in production is more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: I just meant, for example, the actual imlementation is suppose I am storing unique ids of my friends in shared preference, so datatype currently i implemented as `List<String> friends_ids`, now suppose I have to also insert name for every friend_id I am storing, now for this case my new datatype will be `List<Friends> friends` where Friends will be an Class consisting of `user_id` as well as `name`, now as you can see for this example I can convert previous `user_ids` in new shared prefrence variable, wouldn't it be better to restore them?

Comment: In that case, you still shouldn't just change the list of that key. Instead, implement some logic to check if the old key exists, and load the data there into your new list of Friends objects. Then clear the old key and continue using the new one.

Comment: now suppose in version `n` there was other datatype and in version `n+1` there was again different datatype, now I would have to write `if-else` for version number to check how to restore data to new `n+2` version?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur yes, but you shouldn't be doing this anyway. Take some time to plan out what you want to do instead of charging in blindly and realizing you need to change something critical.

Comment: yeah I know I was just asking what can be the possible ways, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't worry about the downgrade scenario, since Google Play doesn't support it. And even if the user manually tries to downgrade (i.e you sharing the user the .apk directly), the shared preferences will be cleared out anyway.
2. There is no migration logic for shared preferences, like the way we have for Databases. So this has to be done manually.
3. My suggestion is to use a different key instead of going through the `if else`. Do this always, since I prefer keeping my code clean, rather than the shared preferences file.

Comment: If you are going to change the key only then also you would have to write the logic to insert previous key values to the new key, and for that you would have to write if-else?